# Solving $2ty''+y'+2ty=0$ centered at 0 using the method of Frobenius.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, frobenius-method

This is what I've got so far:

$$2ty''+y'+2ty=0$$
$$y''+\frac{1}{2t} y + y = 0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} + \frac{1}{2t}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)c_n t^{n+r-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r) +2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$(r(r-1)+2r) c_{0}t^{r-2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r) +2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$(r^2-r)c_{0}t^{r-2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r) +2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$(r^2-r)c_{0}t^{r-2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r) +2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^{n+r}$$
$$(r^2-r)c_{0}t^{r-2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r) +2(n+r)c_n t^{n+r-1} -c_n t^{n+r}$$

In the notes my professor provided, he solves for his $r$ values first, but I cannot follow his steps, and other examples I've found on the internet seem to start off this way. Where do I want to go from here? Should I try to pull out my $c_0$ and $c_1$ terms? Or? Do I need to find my potential $r$ values first? If so, can someone elaborate on how I go about this?

Comment: Just follow [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method#Example).

Comment: Usually the idea is to get the exponents to match and worry about the terms later. Getting the indicial equation corresponds to setting n = 0 , then you can try to explicity solve for the coefficients after getting the roots

Comment: @TnilkImaniq Do my changes to the process look any better?

Comment: @TnilkImaniq Do I simply take my $(r^2-r)$ and state that my zeros are at $0$ and $1$. I'm quite unclear where I want to go from there. I want to end up with some $y$ in $A+B$ form right?

Comment: If you want to get your roots you just have to set $n = 0$ and solve for r